# How to capture RAW JPG with picamera in a python script

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi camera which I am using to take some pictures. I want to take some raw jpg pictures. Upon searching online, I found out that I can accomplish it using the following command:

```
raspistill --raw -o image.jpg
```

However, I want to accomplish the same thing in my script. I do realize that I can use os/subprocess library to execute the above mentioned command in my script. However, I am looking for a particular function in the PiCamera library.

For example, to enable still stats, I can use -st flag to turn it on. However, I can accomplish the same thing using the following line in my python script:

```
camera.still_stats = True
```

Along the same lines, I want to take raw JPG image in my script.

Comment: "RAW JPG" is like "raw baked potato" or "raw well done steak"; it contradicts itself.

Comment: To be clear, the only way to get RAW data from the Raspberry Pi camera is to have it wrapped up in the .jpeg. The RAW data array gets appended to the .jpeg as metadata. Kinda crazy, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `bayer=True` parameter: `camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg', bayer=True)`

This will ask for the bayer data to be encoded in the .jpeg stream.

Answer (score 0):

Umar, what exactly do you mean by "raw jpg?" In photography, JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group) is a universal file format that achieves small file size due to image processing done by computer software or camera software. On the opposite end, a RAW file is a much larger file, because it has had no processing measures applied to it, and thus remains uncompressed.

The command you've given seems to add RAW data to your JPEG file, but, again that doesn't make your photograph "raw." [This thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=146310&start=25) contains the information you are looking for, I believe.

Comment: If you have additional questions, please use the comments. Don't post them as an answer!

Comment: The only way to get RAW data from the Raspberry Pi camera is to have it wrapped up in the .jpeg (resulting in what's generally referred to a RAW+jpeg file). The RAW data array gets appended to the .jpeg as metadata. Kinda crazy, but that's how it works.